# Get OptionMenu value after selection and store in array

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self,master,**kwargs)
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.create_window(0,0,anchor=N+W,window=self.frame)
        self.row = 1
        self.input_n_or_s = []
        self._init_entries()

    def _init_entries(self):
        n_or_s  = Label(self.frame, text='N or S', font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row = self.row, column = 1)
        self.row += 1

    def add_entry(self):
        n_or_s = ['N', 'S']
        variable = StringVar(self.frame)
        variable.set(n_or_s[0])
        option_n_or_s = OptionMenu(self.frame, variable, *n_or_s)                  
        option_n_or_s.grid(row = self.row, column = 1)                     

        self.row += 1

    #def save_entry(self):

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.title('Lot')

    lot = Window(root)
    lot.grid(row=0,column=0)

    scroll = Scrollbar(root)
    scroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)

    lot.config(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
    scroll.config(command=lot.yview)
    lot.configure(scrollregion = lot.bbox("all"), width=1000, height=500)

    def add_points():
        lot.add_entry()
        lot.configure(scrollregion = lot.bbox("all"))

    b1 = Button(root, text = "Add points", command = add_points)
    b1.grid(row=1,column=0)

    def get_value():
        b1.destroy()
        lot.save_entry()

    b2 = Button(root, text = "Get value!", command = get_value)
    b2.grid(row=2,column=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Can someone help me on what to put inside the 'save_entry()' function to get each values of the OptionMenus (assuming that the 'add entry' button has been clicked more than 5 times), and then put each values in the 'input_n_or_s' array for later use?

For example:
Here's the GUI wherein the user clicked the 'Add points' button 10 times, and then changed some default values to 'S':
[image: gui]

My expected output should look like this:
['S', 'N', 'N', 'S', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'S', 'N', 'S']

Answer (score 0):

Here you go I think this is what you want.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self,master,**kwargs)
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.create_window(0,0,anchor=N+W,window=self.frame)
        self.row = 1
        self.input_n_or_s = []
        self._init_entries()

    def _init_entries(self):
        n_or_s  = Label(self.frame, text='N or S', font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row = self.row, column = 1)
        self.row += 1

    def add_entry(self):
        n_or_s = ['N', 'S']
        self.variable = StringVar(self.frame)
        self.variable.set(n_or_s[0])
        self.menu = option_n_or_s = OptionMenu(self.frame, self.variable, *n_or_s)
        option_n_or_s.grid(row = self.row, column=1)

        self.row += 1

    def save_entry(self):
        print(self.variable.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    root.resizable(0, 0)
    root.title('Lot')

    lot = Window(root)
    lot.grid(row=0,column=0)

    scroll = Scrollbar(root)
    scroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)

    lot.config(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
    scroll.config(command=lot.yview)
    lot.configure(scrollregion = lot.bbox("all"), width=1000, height=500)

    root.cnt = 0
    def add_points():
        root.cnt += 1
        if root.cnt < 5:
            return
        root.cnt = 0

        lot.add_entry()
        lot.configure(scrollregion = lot.bbox("all"))
        lot.input_n_or_s.append(lot.variable.get())

    b1 = Button(root, text = "Add points", command = add_points)
    b1.grid(row=1,column=0)

    def get_value():
        b1.destroy()
        lot.save_entry()

    b2 = Button(root, text = "Get value!", command = get_value)
    b2.grid(row=2, column=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what you changed. Otherwise we have to read line-by-line and character-by-character to find what you did differently from the OP.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the output that I want. I edited the question by adding an example and its expected output to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The reason that I can't manage to make it work before is that I'm trying to get the output from the OptionMenu instead of the variable.

```
    def add_entry(self):
        ....
        self.input_n_or_s.append(variable)

    def save_entry(self):
        for entry in self.input_n_or_s:
            x = str(entry.get())
            self.north_or_south.append(x)
        print(self.north_or_south)
```

So here's the whole working code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self,master,**kwargs)
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.create_window(0,0,anchor=N+W,window=self.frame)
        self.row = 1
        self.input_n_or_s = []
        self.north_or_south = []
        self._init_entries()

    def _init_entries(self):
        n_or_s  = Label(self.frame, text='N or S', font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row = self.row, column = 1)
        self.row += 1

    def add_entry(self):
        n_or_s = ['N', 'S']
        variable = StringVar(self.frame)
        variable.set(n_or_s[0])
        option_n_or_s = OptionMenu(self.frame, variable, *n_or_s)                  
        option_n_or_s.grid(row = self.row, column = 1)                     

        self.row += 1

        self.input_n_or_s.append(variable)


    def save_entry(self):
        for entry in self.input_n_or_s:
            x = str(entry.get())
            self.north_or_south.append(x)
        print(self.north_or_south)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.title('Lot')

    lot = Window(root)
    lot.grid(row=0,column=0)

    scroll = Scrollbar(root)
    scroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)

    lot.config(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
    scroll.config(command=lot.yview)
    lot.configure(scrollregion = lot.bbox("all"), width=1000, height=500)

    def add_points():
        lot.add_entry()
        lot.configure(scrollregion = lot.bbox("all"))

    b1 = Button(root, text = "Add points", command = add_points)
    b1.grid(row=1,column=0)

    def get_value():
        b1.destroy()
        lot.save_entry()

    b2 = Button(root, text = "Get value!", command = get_value)
    b2.grid(row=2,column=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Still, thanks for the effort on helping me, Daniel Huckson. And Bryan Oakley, thanks for your concern also.